# Is there a way to find out the necessary users, roles, and privileges an Oracle Dump file needs?

Tags: windows-7, oracle-11g

I've been tasked with importing this old Oracle dump file from beyond my time - as such, the person that did the exporting, and the server on which it originally resides on is long gone.

My knowledge with Oracle is limited, but as far as I know, I can't just restore a database willy-nilly; I need to have the exact same setup of users, roles, privileges it was using.

Problem is, I don't know what those are.

Is there a way to find out the necessary users, roles, and privileges an Oracle Dump file needs? Is it saved on the dump file, perhaps?

Thanks.

System:

- Windows 7
- Oracle 11g XE (though I believe the dump file is from a 9g)

Answer (score 1):

I create a view that has all the roles and privileges that are associated.
Then I select from the view.

```
-- Create the dba_user_privs view:
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW DBA_USER_PRIVS (USERNAME, ROLENAME, PRIVILEGE) AS 
 SELECT DECODE(SA1.GRANTEE#, 1, 'PUBLIC', U1.NAME), SUBSTR(U2.NAME,1,20),  
   SUBSTR(SPM.NAME,1,27)  
FROM SYS.SYSAUTH$ SA1, SYS.SYSAUTH$ SA2, SYS.USER$ U1,  
     SYS.USER$ U2, SYS.SYSTEM_PRIVILEGE_MAP SPM 
WHERE SA1.GRANTEE# = U1.USER# 
  AND SA1.PRIVILEGE# = U2.USER# 
  AND U2.USER# = SA2.GRANTEE# 
  AND SA2.PRIVILEGE# = SPM.PRIVILEGE 
UNION 
 SELECT U.NAME, NULL, SUBSTR(SPM.NAME,1,27) 
FROM SYS.SYSTEM_PRIVILEGE_MAP SPM, SYS.SYSAUTH$ SA, SYS.USER$ U 
WHERE SA.GRANTEE#=U.USER#  
  AND SA.PRIVILEGE#=SPM.PRIVILEGE ;

-- You can now see any of the privileges that are granted to any user:
--set lines 200
--select * from dba_user_privs where username='ALAN';
--col rolename format a8
--col username format a8

--USERNAME ROLENAME PRIVILEGE
---------- -------- ----------------------
--ALAN     DBA      MANAGE FILE GROUP
--ALAN     DBA      MANAGE SCHEDULER
--ALAN     DBA      MANAGE TABLESPACE
--ALAN     DBA      MERGE ANY VIEW
--ALAN     DBA      ON COMMIT REFRESH
--ALAN     DBA      QUERY REWRITE
--ALAN     DBA      READ ANY FILE GROUP
--ALAN     DBA      RESTRICTED SESSION
--ALAN     DBA      RESUMABLE
--ALAN     DBA      SELECT ANY DICTIONARY
--ALAN     DBA      SELECT ANY SEQUENCE
--ALAN     DBA      SELECT ANY TABLE
--ALAN     DBA      SELECT ANY TRANSACTION
--ALAN     DBA      UNDER ANY TABLE
--ALAN     DBA      UNDER ANY TYPE
--ALAN     DBA      UNDER ANY VIEW
--ALAN     DBA      UPDATE ANY TABLE
--ALAN              SELECT ANY DICTIONARY
--ALAN              UNLIMITED TABLESPACE
```